# Unable to resolve "./scenes/main" from "App.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

[image]

Unable to resolve "./scenes/main" from "App.js" .First I was getting an Invariant violation element type error ..Check the render method of ExpoRoot so I created an App.js file in Expo and put the code of my root file screen.js in App.js.

Comment: Unable to resolve "./scenes/main" from "App.js" .First I was getting Invariant violation element type error ..Check render method of ExpoRoot so I created an App.js file in Expo and put the code of my root file screen.js in App.js .Now what to do

Answer (score 0):

the error basically means you are trying to import a file that do not exist.
so just check your imports or give us more code: App.js file

Comment: I didn't have App.js in my project in expo I was using screens.js (as root file ) so i created App.js file to counter "" Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js" error """

Comment: Then check entry point in expo json config file, you probably forgot to change main file